# android design Galaxy 2 and Galaxy 3

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create an android app optimized for Galaxy S2 and Galaxy S3.
I created the images for Galaxy S3 and I put them in the xhdpi folder.
After that I reduce the images 75% and put them in the folder for hdpi (according to Android Guidelines for multi-density).

The problem is that the S2 do not only have lower density also the screen is smaller so the images resized only 75% are too big to be used.

Example: a full width image in Galaxy S3 will be 720px wide, the 75% is 540px that is bigger than 480px wide that I need for full width in Galaxy S2.

The problem is that I have at the same time 2 different densities and 2 different screen sizes.

How can I handle multidensity + multi sreen size?

Should I do it only creating the specific images with the specific sizes for G2 and G3 or there is a way (by code) to tell the phone to auto adjust the image to a certain size (for example I provide an image that is originally width 540px but I tell the phone to rescale it to 480px to be adjusted full width in Galaxy 2.

I'm clear that the images for G3 must be xhdpi and G2 hdpi, but the question is more about how to handle the different screen sizes wisely.

Thanks,

David